# $\displaystyle \sum^{10}_{k=0}\binom{20+k}{20}\cdot \binom{20-k}{10}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

> The value of $\displaystyle \sum^{10}_{k=0}\binom{20+k}{20}\cdot \binom{20-k}{10}$

Using $\displaystyle \binom{n}{r}=\binom{n}{n-r}$

So we have $\displaystyle \sum^{10}_{k=0}\binom{20+k}{k}\cdot \binom{20-k}{10-k}=\binom{40}{10}$

(Above using $2$ way counting ,

we have total $40$ students and we have to select $10$ students)

But answer given as $\displaystyle \binom{41}{10}$

Please have a look on that problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Their answer is right.

Consider the bijection: Choose $31$ from $41$ objects. The location of the $21$st object (at location $21+k$) splits the rest into a selection of $20$ objects from the first $20+k$ and a selection of $10$ from the last $20-k$. Similarly, a selection of the latter sort can be subsumed into a selection of $31$ from $41$ objects.

Alternatively, $1/(1-z)^{n+1}=\sum_{k=0} ((n+k)Cn )x^k$, so the first binomial is the coefficients of $z^k$ in $1/(1-z)^{21}$, the second of $z^{10-k}$ in  $1/(1-z)^{11}$, and the total sumproduct is the coefficient of $z^{10}$, which gives that you want the coefficient of $z^{10}$ of $1/(1-z)^{32}$ which gives $(32+10-1)C31=41C10$.

Comment: +1 : Wow. Nice answer.

Comment: For what its worth, it took me a few moments to visualize the Stars and Bars computation that led to the conclusion in the last sentence of your posting; and I am extremely familiar with Stars and Bars.  You might wish to add a couple of paragraphs to the end of your answer, explaining the computation of the coefficient of $~z^{10}.$

Comment: I just used the formula from the first sentence of the paragraph for the generating function of $1/(1-z)^{n+1}$. It’s $z^{10}$ because $10=k+(10-k)$. There’s no combinatorial reasoning in the second argument, although I am taking the generating function of $1/(1-z)^{n+1}$ for granted which I suppose you could prove with either Stars and Bars or just induction.

Answer (score 1):

Here we  have  a  *[Chu-Vandermonde Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity)*  in disguise.

> We obtain:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum^{10}_{k=0}\binom{20+k}{k}\binom{20-k}{10-k}}
> &=\sum^{10}_{k=0}\binom{-21}{k}\binom{-11}{10-k}\tag{1}\\
> &=\binom{-32}{10}\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{41}{10}}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$ twice.
- In (2) we apply the *Chu-Vandermonde* identity.
- In (3) we apply the binomial identity used in (1) again.